# Setting Multi-Select field with values from a text field

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am new to NetSuite scripting and learning as I go. I needed values from a text field to set the values in a Multi Select field for Custom Record. This is running in SuiteScript 1.0. (According to people I spoke to, NetSuite does not have a native function to paste mass custom record names in a Multi Select field so the suggestion was to have a text field and an AfterSubmit event.)

My script works in a beforeSubmit event but now trying to work out multiple values rather than singular. See **test** script below:

```js
function beforeSubmit(type) {
    var existId = checkStr(nlapiGetFieldValue('custevent_ids'));

    if (checkStr(existId) == '') {
        var testIds = nlapiGetFieldValue('custevent_add_ids');
        nlapiSetFieldText('custevent_ids', testIds);
    }
}
```

I tried different variation of arrays to set the field with multiple custom record names but I just get blank, but singular it sets the custom record.

Thanks for helping a newbie out

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568220/how-to-set-value-for-the-multi-select-field-using-netsuite-suitescript-2-0-versi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are asking using SuiteScript 2.0:

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
    var existId = context.newRecord.getValue('custevent_ids');

    if (existId != null) {
        var loadedRec = record.load({ type: 'customrecord_your_record_type', id: context.newRecord.id });

        var testIds = loadedRec.getValue('custevent_add_ids');
        var arrayIds = testIds.split('\r\n');
        log.debug('array', arrayIds);

        loadedRec.setText('custevent_ids', arrayIds);
        loadedRec.save();
    }
}
```

I haven't worked with SuiteScript 1.0 but here are a few things I think you are missing:

- The record must be loaded in order to set Select fields (per Krypton's comment)
- You must split the input field text into an array separated by \r\n
- If you do use SS 1.0, be sure to use the `nlapiSetFieldTexts` method to set the Multi-Select field

Comment: I’ll test this out and update you. Thanks

Comment: this worked brilliantly! Highly appreciate it. At least there's a baseline now I can work on and iron out other errors.