# How to set multiple values in a custom NetSuite mult-select field

Tags: netsuite, sailpoint, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to set multiple values using SailPoint in a NetSuite multi-select field.   Currently the script below allows me to set one value in the field.  If I try to set a 2nd value in the field, it overwrites the first value instead of adding the 2nd value.  How do I need to update the code below to assign a second value in the field instead of overwriting the current value?

```
{
&quot;custentity_employee_property_assign_v2&quot;: { 
    &quot;items&quot;:[{ 
    &quot;id&quot; : &quot;$plan.empPropertyid$&quot; 
    }]
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value for the multi-select field using netsuite suitescript 2.0 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568220/how-to-set-value-for-the-multi-select-field-using-netsuite-suitescript-2-0-versi)